# Ruby multidimensional array assignment disparities

Tags: ruby

Can someone please explain the difference in output between these two cases:

```
array = [['a', 'a,'], ['a', 'a']]
# => [['a', 'a,'], ['a', 'a']]
array[0][0] = 'b'
# => 'b'
array
# => [['b', 'a'], ['a', 'a']]
```

and

```
array = [['a'] * 2] * 2
# => [['a', 'a,'], ['a', 'a']]
array[0][0] = 'b'
# => 'b'
array
# => [['b', 'a'], ['b', 'a']]
```

It seems when using the form `[['a'] * 2] * 2` to create the multi-dimensional array, changes to the first 'row' are duplicated in every row?

Is there an alternative short-form way to define a multidimensional array that doesn't have this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your second technique is that you are creating a single array `['a', 'a']` and putting it in both positions in the `array` array. You need to `clone` the items in `array` so they aren't literally the same item.

```
array = [['a'] * 2] * 2
# => [["a", "a"], ["a", "a"]]
array.map! { |item| item.clone }
# => [["a", "a"], ["a", "a"]] 
array[0][0] = 'b'
# => "b"
array
# => [["b", "a"], ["a", "a"]]
```

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense. Out of interest, Is there an alternative short-hand approach to creating multidimensional arrays that wouldn't require the cloning step?

Comment: No, there's no short-hand. You have to either `clone` or add each item separately. The shortest way to do that is suggested by hbejgel by using `times`.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `[['a'] * 2] * 2` you are creating a single Array Object `['a', 'a']` with two references to it in the outer Array. To accomplish what you want you'd have to write.

```
array = []
2.times do
   array << ['a']*2
end
```

This way you're creating a new inner array at each iteration and they should be independent from one another.